# How does compareTo work? (Comparable Interface) Java 8

Tags: java, comparable

I don't get the concept of compareTo. From what I read, since it is an interface, we get to decide how one object is compared to another (We define what it means for one object to be greater than, equal to, and less than another object). But when you use the compareTo method, it returns an integer. How does that connect? What do we do with that integer? How does this connect to the sort method?
**Example scenario**: You are comparing two strings. You want to sort them so the string with the most letters goes first. **Question**: How do you set that up?

Comment: Have you read the [javadoc](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Comparable.html) for `Comparable`?

Comment: I have read it and I've read other documentation and had others try to explain it to me but for some reason I just can't get my head around it...

Comment: What about it is confusing you the most?

Comment: The key part is "Returns a negative integer, zero, or a positive integer as this object is less than, equal to, or greater than the specified object."

Comment: The part about it returning an integer value. I don't know what that does/what we do with it. Also, I don't get how it is connected to the sort method.

Comment: Go through this [link](https://www.javatpoint.com/java-string-compareto). This will make your head clear if you know what lexicographical means.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let's get right to the heart of the matter.  Imagine we have a class `K` that we've defined as implementing `Comparable<K>`, and two references `a` and `b` to objects of class `K`.

To know if `a` is "less thanb`, we write

```
if (a.compareTo(b) < 0) {
     //  compareTo returned a negative number
     ,,,
}
```

To know if `a` is "equal to" `b`, we write

```
if (a.compareTo(b) == 0) {
    // compareTo returned zero
    ...
}
```

And to know if `a` is "greater than" `b`, we write

```
if (a.compareTo(b) > 0) {
    // compareTo returned a positive integer
    ...
}
```

Does that clear things up a bit?

Comment: Yes, that clears things up a bit, thank you. How does that relate to the sort method? Say, if I sorted a list that had objects a and b, if I wanted to sort the list so that the "greater than" of the two comes first, do I use the third bit of code?

Comment: If you are writing the sort routine yourself, then Yes, you'd use that third pattern to decide that `a` should sort ahead of `b`.

Answer (score 1):

Sorting list of Custom Objects in ascending and descending Order

Java provides two interfaces to sort objects using data members of the class:

**Comparable and 
Comparator interfaces**

Java Comparable interface

Java Comparable interface is used to order the objects of user-defined class.
This interface is found in java.lang package and contains only one method named compareTo(Object).
It provide single sorting sequence only i.e. you can sort the elements on based on single data member only. 
public int compareTo(Object obj): is used to compare the current object with the specified object.
We can sort the elements of:
String objects
Wrapper class objects
User-defined class objects

**Java Comparator interface**

Java Comparator interface is used to order the objects of user-defined class.
Collections class provides static methods for sorting the elements of collection.
Method of Collections class for sorting List elements
public void sort(List list, Comparator c): is used to sort the elements of List by the given Comparator.

References: http://corejavapractical.blogspot.in/2017/08/algorithms-in-java.html

```
package com.mycompany.projectname.corejava;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.Collections;
import java.util.Comparator;
import java.util.Date;
import java.util.Iterator;
import java.util.LinkedList;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.ListIterator;
import java.util.concurrent.CopyOnWriteArrayList;


public class AlgorithmsDemo {

         public static void main(String[] args) {
                 //sortingCustomObjectsByComparable();
                 sortingCustomObjectsByComparator();
         }


         private static void sortingCustomObjectsByComparable(){

                 // Sort Projects by project id in ascending order.

                 List projects = new ArrayList<>();
                 Project project = new Project();
                 project.setProjectId(100);
                 project.setProjectName("project 100");
                 projects.add(project);

                 Project project2 = new Project();
                 project2.setProjectId(200);
                 project2.setProjectName("project 200");
                 projects.add(project2);

                 Project project3 = new Project();
                 project3.setProjectId(50);
                 project3.setProjectName("project 50");
                 projects.add(project3);

                 Collections.sort(projects);

                 printList(projects);

         }

         private static void sortingCustomObjectsByComparator(){

                 // Sort Projects by project id in ascending order.

                 List projects = new ArrayList<>();
                 Project project = new Project();
                 project.setProjectId(100);
                 project.setProjectName("project 100");
                 projects.add(project);

                 Project project2 = new Project();
                 project2.setProjectId(200);
                 project2.setProjectName("project 200");
                 projects.add(project2);

                 Project project3 = new Project();
                 project3.setProjectId(50);
                 project3.setProjectName("project 50");
                 projects.add(project3);

                 // Sorting project by project id in ascending order in Java
                 Collections.sort(projects);
                 printList(projects);

                 // Sorting project by project id in descending order in Java
        Collections.sort(projects, Collections.reverseOrder());
        printList(projects);


     // Sorting project by project name in ascending order in Java
          Comparator comparator = new Comparator() {
               @Override
               public int compare(Project o1, Project o2) {
                   // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                   return o1.getProjectName().compareTo(o2.getProjectName());
               }
          };
           Collections.sort(projects, comparator);
           printList(projects);

         }

         private static void printList(List projects){
                 for(Project project : projects){
                          System.out.println(project.getProjectId());
                          System.out.println(project.getProjectName());
                 }
         }

}

class Project implements Comparable{
         private int projectId;
         private String projectName;
         public int getProjectId() {
                 return projectId;
         }
         public void setProjectId(int projectId) {
                 this.projectId = projectId;
         }
         public String getProjectName() {
                 return projectName;
         }
         public void setProjectName(String projectName) {
                 this.projectName = projectName;
         }
         @Override
         public int compareTo(Project o) {
                 // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                 return this.projectId - o.getProjectId();
         }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

http://www.javapractices.com/topic/TopicAction.do?Id=10
This link gives good guidelines on implementing compareTo.

When you have a class that you need to order instances of, compareTo comes in handy. When you implement compareTo, You are basically telling the sortmethod how different instances of your class *compare to* each other.

Suppose you had a class Student that owned an integer Age, a double GPA, and a string Name, you could really sort instances of Student by any one of these fields. However, you decide you want to sort based on the Age. You would then implement the compareTo function to return feedback based on the Age instead of the other two fields.

Comment: If I were you, I would ask a follow up question focusing on your example scenario. Use appropriate tags and specifically ask for the use and implementation of a sort method and a compareTo method...